# SQLite: Query for Latitude/Longitude Delta

Tags: sqlite, geolocation, geospatial

I have a SQLite table with fields **Latitude** and **Longitude** (neg and pos numbers)

I have a **latitude** **delta** and a **longitude** **delta** of (for example '23') based on a Latitude of 50 and a longitude of 75 (again, for example)

How do I query the table for a list of all records which are + or - 23 latitudes and + or - 23 longitudes when there are both positive and negative latitude and longitude values in the table.

The lat/long fields are of type NUMERIC and are indexed ASC.

```
select [fields] 
   from [table] 
      where latitude of 50 -+23 and
            longitude of 75 -+23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Lookup the delta and stating values first
2. Calculate the +/- values based on the delta and the starting values per-record
3. Use the ["BETWEEN operator"](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) to get the result (scroll down on that link to find the info)

If you're using an ORM between you and the database, or a programming language on top of the DB, you might be able to do steps 1 and 2 on the fly, thereby only executing one DB query in step 3.